# Is it possible to make a window withouth a top in GLUT?

Tags: opengl, glut

When you make a window in glut using glutCreateWindow it puts a top to the window? What if I want to do some OpenGL rendering without a window top?

This probably doesn't make much sense without a picture:

[image: Window Top]

Essentially I want to remove this from the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper terminology for what you want is "undecorated window" or "borderless window". Unfortunately, I can't find any GLUT calls which let you control window decorations.

The closest I *was* able to find was `glutFullScreen` which, on X11 platforms, is often implemented by maximizing an undecorated window... but it'll re-decorate it if you un-maximize it.

[This forum thread](http://objectmix.com/graphics/241755-glut-window-no-window-decorations.html) seems to confirm my conclusions.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. I guess I'll have to ask another question related to undercoating a window.

Comment: Cars are undercoated, windows are undecorated (lacking decorations). As for making an undecorated window with GLUT, if you do it, it'll be specific to the platform you're on and I've only seen hacks to do it on X11.

Answer (score 8):

Use GLUT_BORDERLESS and GLUT_CAPTIONLESS as additional parameters to the glutInitDisplayMode() to get rid of window border and caption as follow:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA|GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_DEPTH|GLUT_BORDERLESS|GLUT_CAPTIONLESS);
```

At least it works pretty good with freeglut 2.8.1 on Windows.

[image]