# Cross platform solution to undecorating a window?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799803/is-it-possible-to-make-a-window-withouth-a-top-in-glut).

Since, it I can't use GLUT to undecorated windows is there a **cross-platform** (which should include Mac, Windows, and Ubuntu at minimum) library or way to undecorated a window? I know there are ways to do this for individual operating systems but, I wanted a cross platform way to do it, so I looked at GLUT. Unfortunately, the only option is glutFullScreen which I do not want.

(And can it be in C++ or C too?)

Comment: pmg: Fine, I'll specify cross-platform as: Mac, Windows, and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at borderless windows in [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/).

[Making a borderless window with for Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235360/looking-for-qt-styling-with-borderless-window-tutorial-or-how-to)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use freeglut to undecorate windows.
See the second answer to the question [Is it possible to make a window withouth a top in GLUT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799803/is-it-possible-to-make-a-window-withouth-a-top-in-glut?answertab=oldest#tab-top)